# Select from table with 2 condition and 2 operations

Tags: sql, sql-view

I have a Table BoxTrans
the table Contain Rows (ID,Date,FromBox,ToBox,Value)
I want to make a View like (ID,Date,Box,ValueIn,ValueOut)
select when frombox Give Value to ValueOut
and when tobox Give Value to ValueIN

Comment: Maybe clarify what you want with a short example.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `CASE` statement to check the value of a different column when populating a column. The below query will return your output as long as either ToBox or FromBox is NULL, if they are both not null you may get unexpected results.

```
SELECT ID, 
Date,
COALESCE(ToBox,FromBox) as Box, 
CASE WHEN ToBox IS NOT NULL THEN value ELSE NULL as ValueIn,
CASE WHEN FromBox IS NOT NULL THEN value ELSE NULL as ValueOut
FROM BoxTrans
```